# Proof that finite fields cannot be pseudo-algebraically closed

Tags: commutative-algebra, finite-fields, affine-varieties

I'm studying pseudo-finite fields in particular on Chatzidakis notes. When dealing with the concept of pseudo-algebraically closed (PAC) fields, it is stated that they cannot be finite but without any proof. I've tried to figure out a proof by myself trying to find an absolutely irreducible polynomial over a generic finite field $F_q$ and show it doesn't admit an $F_q$-rational point but I suspect this cannot work. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $2\nmid q$ I have the following example: $y^2 = x^q - x + d$, where $d\in \Bbb F_q$ is not a square.

It is easy to see that this equation defines an absolutely irreducible variety and has no $\Bbb F_q$ point.

I believe you can also modify it to an example in char $2$.

Comment: May be $(x^q-x)(y^q-y)=1$ works for all $q$?

Comment: @Jyrki Ah yes, or even $(x^q-x)y=1$.

Comment: This seems to work thank you very much!